# Can a prepositional phrase act as an indirect object?

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases, direct-objects, indirect-objects

For example, in the sentence: I baked a cake for my mom.

Direct object (DO): cake
Indirect object (IO): for my mom

Some webpages say [IO can only come before DO](http://www.softschools.com/examples/grammar/indirect_object_examples/77/)

While others explain that [a prepositional phrase can also act as IO](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/indirectobject.htm)

Can a prepositional phrase act as an indirect object?

Comment: "For my mom" is a prepositional phrase.  "My mom" is the object of the preposition "for".  But the second website is correct in that a prepositional phrase such as the one in the example serves the same function as an indirect object; "I baked my mom a cake" is the same semantically as "I baked a cake for my mom."

Comment: @Steven Littman, Alejandra A simple golden rule: If the phrase has a preposition it, it cannot be an indirect object. Although _I baked a cake for my mom_ has the same meaning as _I baked my mom a cake_, the syntactic structure is different and the PP _for my mom_ is not an indirect object. Thus the complement of the prep "for" (i.e. "my mom") is an 'oblique', an object of the preposition rather than of the verb "baked".

Comment: I didn't say a prepositional phrase can be an indirect object.  But if my guess is correct and Alejandra's native language is Spanish, it can cause some confusion because Spanish grammar considers such an object an indirect object; in the sentence “Le cociné un bizcocho para mi mamá”, "le" is the enclitic (redundant) indirect object referring to the object "mi mamá”.

Comment: I've no closevotes left today, but this looks to me like a duplicate of [What's wrong with “I'll open you the door”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door)

Comment: @BillJ So, what is the prepositional phrase "for my mom" in part of sentence? Adverbial ?

Comment: @towry It's a complement of the verb "baked".

Comment: @BillJ Yes, but it is also an [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(linguistics)) of the verb "baked". In part of sentence, I think it is a adverbial to modify the verb.

Comment: @towry  Adjuncts (adverbials) are not arguments.

Comment: @BillJ, So, it is adverbial ...

Comment: @towry No, no, no! You said it was an argument of "baked" and an adverbial, to which I replied that adjuncts (adverbials) are not arguments of the verb, i.e. what you're suggesting is impossible. I've told you, it's a complement. Please take that on board.

Comment: It is an adverbial adjunct, can be removed. It's not an argument of the verb, and it's not a complement of the verb. It's an adverbial.

Comment: @towry What are you talking about? Of course it's an argument of the verb and thus cannot be an adjunct. It is a complement just like direct and indirect objects are. Go learn English grammar!

Comment: You are right !

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a benefactive such as "for my mum" behaves like an indirect object, in that it can often appear before the direct object without the preposition:

> I baked my mum a cake.
>
> She sewed me a shirt.

But this is not natural for all verbs, and I'm not sure what rule will predict it. So

> ? He dug me the garden.

does not sound right to me whereas "He dug the garden for me" is fine.

I think the availability of this construction depends on whether the actor ends up providing an object rather than just a service to the beneficient, but I'm not sure. Consider

> She painted me a picture.

which is fine, but

> ? She painted me the house.

which sounds odd to my ear.

Comment: Interesting point, Colin, but I must say to my US ears, "to dig the garden" sounds strange to me in general.  What does that mean to you?  Plant seeds?  Turn the soil in preparation for planting?  I garden a lot, and I never have heard that phrase on the western shores of the Pond.

Comment: Hm. It's normal for me, and it refers to preparing the soil. But GloWbE has only 12 instances of it - 5 from GB, 2 from US; so it hasn't been used much on the web. BNC (the British National Corpus) has 5, and COCA (Contemporary American English) only 1.

Comment: We might say "till the soil" for that in the US.  In fact, we'd rent a machine called a rototiller that would be available at a reasonable rate for four hours' rental, and it would be more than enough time!

Comment: "Till the soil" sounds like something out of the bible to me! I know that machine as a "rotovator" (which I think is actually a tradename).. I've never heard "rototiller".

Comment: 'He paid the entire amount for me' and 'He paid me the entire amount' are both acceptable but don't show the benefactive alternation.

Comment: Indeed. _Pay_ is already ditransitive, so will not accept a benefactive without explicit marking.

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been bothering me lately... sometimes teaching ESL really sucks... She gave the chemicals to the lab.  She submitted the chemicals to the lab.  She gave the lab the chemicals. She submitted the lab the chemicals... all seem to mean the same thing and to have the same functions for their parts... but the last one is the odd man out... also in the above example someone gave about painting... as in She painted me the house... which I would say is NOT the same thing as She painted the house for me... unless you mean she painted a picture of the house for you.. and did not paint an actual house... grrrr... trying to get this across to low-level speakers is interesting at best...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This (excluding the complaint) has already been said at ['Fix me that account' or 'fix that account for me](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79573/fix-me-that-account-or-fix-that-account-for-me/79578#79578) (though [some](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6868/ed03eb4c111c28c18b1392ddcdfb3295b7c8.pdf) distinguish ditransitive and benefactive constructions, rather than seeing the latter as a subclass). 'Ditransitive constructions in English ... occur idiosyncratically ... rather than predictably.... Mukherjee gives a good analytical overview of prototypical to peripheral examples....'