# Verbs which do not take indirect object pronouns

Tags: pronouns, indirect-objects

I have a book with exercises of the type:

> My uncle sent a book to my sister.

Which should be transformed as:

> My uncle sent my sister a book.

There are some which do not seem to work well:

> Our teacher explained physics to us.
>   Our teacher explained us physics.

Or:

> Could you suggest a good book to me.  Could you suggest me a good book.

I can't find a rule for when this is incorrect. Or, if not a rule, at least a list of verbs which have this property.

Comment: I think you’re looking at this a bit backwards. Many verbs license a prepositional phrase starting in _to_ as an argument; that doesn’t really mean anything in itself. The confusing factor is that, with those relatively few verbs that can take indirect objects, the IO can nearly always be converted into a PP starting in _to_, which is formally indistinguishable from a regular _to_-phrase. So it’s not a matter of not being able to turn a _to_-phrase into an IO, but a matter of being able to take IOs in the first place.

Comment: @Janus Some would consider 'He baked her a cake' a ditransitive construction; benefactives don't require verbs accepting an IO.

Comment: @Edwin True—benefactives further complicate the matter, preferring normally _for_ over _to_.

Comment: @Janus Then there's 'I envied Joan her new car'; I've seen this analysed as a double DO construction. 'For' doesn't really work here IMO.

Comment: @Edwin Double DO makes most sense there to me too; there’s no benefactive, either. _For_ works, but with the car, not with Joan, and I would certainly look askance at anyone claiming the car is the beneficiary!

Comment: Closely related: [fix me that account ... or ... fix that account for me?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79573/fix-me-that-account-or-fix-that-account-for-me?rq=1).

Comment: Many indirect objects are nouns which inflected languages would express as the dative case, so they can be transformed in English using 'to' as the first comment states. Thus they become prepositional phrases once transformed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any "rule" that makes it possible to recognize a specific verb as being ditransitive or not, so my initial reaction was "consult a dictionary", however some online dictionaries seem to be lacking in this regard. I am quite surprised that neither [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/send) nor [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/send) make any mention of *send* being ditransitive.

[macmillandictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/send) uses an example to show that it is ditransitive:

> send someone something: I’ll send you a copy of the report.

[cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/send) and [oxforddictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/send) mention it can be used "with two objects":

> [ + two objects ] I'll send her a letter/email/parcel/postcard next week. (*cambridge*)
>   [with two objects] ‘he sent her a nice little note’ (*oxford*)

This does not help much if you want to quickly check if a verb can be ditransitive, because if it is not mentioned, it may still mean the dictionary simply doesn't mention it, even if it is correct to use a verb with an indirect object.

Searching for "ditransitive verbs" does yield several lists of examples, though, like [this Australian list](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/ditransitive.html). And indeed, that list does not contain *explain* and *suggest*.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb), at least, distinguishes ditransitive verb constructions from other isomorphic {verb + 2 object} constructions: << In grammar, a ditransitive verb is a verb which takes a subject and two objects which refer to a theme and a recipient....  English has a number of generally ditransitive verbs, such as give, grant, and tell and many transitive verbs that can take an additional argument (commonly a beneficiary or target of the action), such as pass, read, bake, etc. >>

Comment: The list of verbs that may be used with two objects that I've compiled further (to the list in the answer) includes advance / allot / answer / apportion / bag / bear / begrudge / bequeath / bid / cite / collect /  envy / fax / fling / gather / grab / hear / kick / knit / lease / paint / pick / pose / produce / reserve / select / sew / shoot / sing / stand / telephone / toss / wire. One or two of these may be in dispute. // Analysis is given by Timothy Colleman & Bernard De Clerck, and in 'English Ditransitive Verbs: Aspects of Theory ... - by Joybrato Mukherjee' (some parts available online).